# Vector tiles in Openlayers as WMS

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector-tiles

I can make a vector tiles request with valid response against Geoserver as WMS but in OL you seem to have to use a `ol.source.VectorTile` source which is some kind of xyz-url. 
Perhaps WMS is possible as a tileloadfunction?

Comment: Can you maybe describe the problem a bit more in detail? From the comment to the answer below I get that you would like to use vectortiles. Have you followed this tutorial? http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html So it is definitely possible to use vector tiles in OpenLayers, just use that xyz-url which is provided in the example. Leave the "{z}/{x}/{-y}" part of the url untouched that is how OpenLayers knows how to create the tiles. If you tried this and it is not working please show your code

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to configure the GeoServer GeoWebCache on top of your WMS, see the GeoServer tutorial:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. Makes no sense that tiles are much more efficient than web map service. Create raster tiles from your vector tiles using tileserver GL by Klokantech. To load a custom stylesheet so that it will render your vector tiles with the proper styling.  Easy to set up it's already a docker container

Comment: You can cache the tiles server side with geowebcache for good performance. I want to style the data client side, therefore I want to use vector tiles.

Comment: Serve your vector tiles from AWS S3 Bucket Just use tippecanoe to produce data and option for folder instead of mbtiles and option for no compression/don't gzip PBF